# If $H$ and $K$ are finite supgroups of a group $G$, then $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to prove following statement:

If $H$ and $K$ are finite supgroups of a group $G$, then $$|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$$

This is a proposition 13 in Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra* chapter 3.3.

Intuitively, I can guess the order of $|HK|$ is proportional to $|H|$ and $|K|$ modulo some intersection.

The textbook states, 
\begin{align}
HK = \bigcup_{h\in H} hK
\end{align}
then it suffices to show that there are $\frac{|H|}{|H\cap K|}$ distinct cosets in this union.

I can understand the division of $HK$ as a sum of $hK$, but I'm having trouble understanding the next step.

Can you explain this in more detail?

Perhaps another proof of this will be helpful.

---

I have found same problem in

[How to prove that $|HK| = \dfrac{|H| \; |K|}{|H \cap K|}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909669/how-to-prove-that-hk-dfrach-kh-cap-k?rq=1)

Now I have some sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $h,h' \in H$ you have $$hK = h'K \iff hh'^{-1} \in K \iff hh'^{-1}\in H\cap K$$
Therefore for fixed $h$ there are exactly $|H\cap K|$ elements $h'\in H$ such that $hK = h'K$, and $hK$ is of cardinal $|K|$. We also proved that the intersections of the cosets is empty.

Thus the result follows.